# Use Guard to trap all enum states other than one

Tags: swift, enums, guard

Hitting a block on using a guard. Ideally want to do a guard statement that traps all enum states other than one, so would be something like:

```
guard case .notInUse != foundTransition.validToObject.isInSituation else { 
   fatalError("Transition: The toObject is already in a situation")
}
```

But this non matching test does not seem to be allowed. So instead using the below if statement:

```
if case .notInUse = foundTransition.validToObject.isInSituation {} else {
   fatalError("Transition: The toObject is already in a situation")
}
```

It works but feels a guard would be neater. Any ideas?

Comment: `guard case !( .notInUse == foundTransition.validToObject.isInSituation) else {fatalError("Transition: The toObject is already in a situation")}`

Comment: Yep tried that but comes up with an failure: Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

Comment: You don't need a negative here. `guard case .notInUse = foundTransition.validToObject.isInSituation else { fatalError("...") }`. You want a fatal error if the value is *not* `notInUse`, right?

Comment: Note that your attempt at the guard statement is saying the opposite of what your if statement says. Your guard statement says "fatal error if the enum value *is* `notInUse`", and your if statement says "fatal error if the enum value *is not* `notInUse`". Which one do you want?

Comment: Yep the logic is a bit confusing! I am attempting to get a fatal error if the enum is NOT notInUse. There are three other enum values all of which should cause a fatal error and execution only proceeds if the enum is notInUse (ie I could put all within an if statement). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to negate a `case` statement.

You either need to use your `if` statement, or make the enumeration `Equatable`, in which case you would just drop the case keyword.

```swift
guard foundTransition.validToObject.isInSituation != .notInUse
```

Alternatively, you can use a `guard` statement that is backed by a `switch` or `if`. But you'll never get rid of them!

```swift
guard ({
  if case .notInUse = foundTransition.validToObject.isInSituation {
    return false
  }
  return true
} ()) else {
  fatalError("Transition: The toObject is already in a situation")
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for that. Will try the Equatable approach, the if works but just feels a bit messy.